# Internet Explorer & Firefox converts inline CSS to weird stuff

Tags: javascript, html, css, inline

I have some HTML that I insert into a div using javascript. But it converts the inline CSS to something weird. Like for example if I put in the div the following HTML (using `document.getElementById("element").innerHTML = ...`):

```
<td valign=top style= border: 0; padding: 0;>
```

When I see what is actually in the div element(using FireBug) this is what it is:

```
<TD vAlign=top 0; padding:>
```

**Is it me that is causing this error somehow? Do you find this happens to you also when you insert some HTML with inline CSS into a div using javascript? Any info would be really helpful**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Attribute values must have *quotes* around them:

```
<td valign="top" style="border: 0; padding: 0;">
```

Also, since this HTML is embedded as a string in Javascript, be careful with the quotes. I recommend single quotes (`'`) to start/end Javascript strings, and double quotes (`"`) to start/end attribute values:

```
document.getElementById('element').innerHTML =
    '<td valign="top" style="border: 0; padding: 0;">';
```

Answer (score 4):

have you tried quoting your attributes?

```
<td valign="top" style="border: 0; padding: 0;">
```

also, note that valign="top" is very much deprecated. use

```
vertical-align: top;
```

lastly, I would strongly urge you to avoid inline css.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping them in quotation marks:

```
<td valign=top style="border: 0; padding: 0;">
```